# Separated loading animation for each div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to load separated loading animations into one page. For example I have to following concept:

- 1. loading animation gets displayed (in the middle of the screen, via css).
- the page is ready, gets displayed; 1. loading gets hidden.
- on the page are several php scripts (via ajax) in separated divs, that get content of a mysql database.
- while the php scripts load, i want to put a loading animation in every div, that loads a php script.

The questions are: how should the loading animations be scripted, so that they don't interfere each other? And how should I build the html/css to this?

I guess it will be something like this: every div gets another div with the loading animation in it. each one with the same ID but a different class. Jquery will hide/show the different class with the callback of the ajax-function. Is this ok? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: got it done myself after trying it after sending the question... :s something like that [link]http://jsfiddle.net/8WG2L/1/